# Ember.Select throwing Error in #each helper

Tags: ember.js

I've been wrestling with the for longer than I care to admit. I am trying to load some data from a local store, set the returned value as my model at the route layer, and then render an `Ember.Select` using that content. Pretty simple stuff right?

Here's my route, where I am loading the data:

```
App.IdentityRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      MuttrChat.models.Identity.find({}, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }

        resolve({ identities: results });
      });
    });
  },
  actions: {
    ready: function() {
      this.transitionTo('inboxes');
    }
  }
});
```

Okay, great, this works. My controller doesn't contain anything relevant to the question (just an action), so I'll spare you the death by syntax-highlighting. Here's the snippet from my template I am trying to render:

```
{{#if model.identities}}
  <li>
    {{view 'select' classNames='topcoat-select' content=model.identities value=selectedIdentity size=6 optionValuePath='content.userID'}}
  </li>
{{/if}}
```

If the results from the query are empty (i.e. this block does not run), everything is fine, however when I have results (which is the whole point), Ember throws, giving me:

> Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an
>   Array. You passed [[object Object],[object Object]]

This is driving me nuts, since that's **clearly an array**! I've tried all kinds of ugly hacks using `Ember.A` and `Ember.ArrayProxy`, but they all eventually lead the that same error.

Any help here is *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

And, it turns out the the results returns from the storage adapter are in fact **not** an *acual* array... -.-

Thank you Ember, you were right all along.

Comment: What code change did u make? I had this same issue and I wrapped the array in Em.A(). Im curious since that didn't work for you.

Comment: I just cast the array like object that my storage adapter return to a real Array with: `Array.apply(null, results)`